# I get Formula parse error with all formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, syntax-error

I want to use basic functions in google spredsheets (which works just fine in excel) but I get

> "Formula parse error"

on all of them.

For example, there is table where date is in one column, and according value in second. I want to extract, into another sheet, value from the 1st week to the first row, value from the week +1 to second etc....

```
=OFFSET(A2, 1, 0)
=OFFSET(A2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

I get Parse formula error. It is happenning also with other formulas, LEFT, CONCATENATE etc... Is there anything wrong in the way I write them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be a locale issue. Some locales use a comma as argument separators, others (e.g. some European countries) use semi-colons (;).
So maybe try changing your comma's into semi-colons?

Comment: You can change the local under `File`->`Spreadsheet settings`